# Is there a way to autoclose curly braces for string interpolation in dart in vscode?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, interpolation

Is there a way to autoclose the curly braces when I use string interpolation in dart?

When I write `'this is a ${'` I want the closing `}` to be automatically added.

Is there a VS Code extension or even just a setting for this functionality?

Comment: Are you wanting something like this: `"editor.autoClosingBrackets": always`

Comment: Also here's an extension that might help: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aliariff.auto-add-brackets

Comment: Thanks! That's exactely what I was looking for